# net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR with jquery XMLHttpRequest on IIS 10 with HTTP2

Tags: jquery, ssl, xmlhttprequest, http2, iis-10

i have a website [www.sampledomain.com](http://www.sampledomain.com) developed into .NET Frameowkr 4, hosted on Windows Server 2016 Production with HTTP2 actived by default with UCC SSL Certificate NOT SelfSigned.

This website works fine with http2 and https (TLS1.2) and it integrates same jquery XMLHttpRequest POST versus same-domain ASMX that works fine in HTTP2 and HTTP1.2 (depend on Browser Vailability)

Now, i have to preparare a pre-production twin server to test security and new features.
All other website copied to pre-production twin server works fine with HTTPS. There is only this web-application that has problem with XMLHttpRequest, showing the error in Chrome COnsole

```
POST https://www.sampledomain.com/asmxservice.asmx/getUserLogged net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
send @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5
ajax @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5
getUserLogged @ login-bs.js:132
controlLogged @ login-bs.js:63
(anonymous) @ login-bs.js:33
j @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
ready @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
J @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
```

The website has a **strict-origin-when-cross-origin** as Referrer Policy.

following packet exchange on wireshar
[packets][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTpec.png

I check SSL certificate and test with another certificate and self seigned certificate, but there aren't changes, only disabling HTTP2 and using HTTP/1.1 works fine with XHR

Comment: I have been more research with wireshark decrypting http2 and i have this [Protocol error][1]

seems that windows server sent Protocol Error with max concurrent streams to 100

but with production server there aren't any of this error [production_ok][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pFTL.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmQMT.png